# Scrolling text automatically for a typing testing app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im new to reactjs, and there are so many things that I have to learn. I'm trying to make an application look like Monkeytype but using reactjs only (not using redux either). I found that in MonkeyType, when I typed nearly to the bottom of the text, there was a nice effect that automatically scrolled the paragraph down to the new field.
[image: Monkey type screen]

To be more clear, when I finish the second line, the screen will automatically move down to show more lines for me to type.
Im trying to mimic that cool effect; however, I can't find a way to make the program know where and how to scroll down.
This is my code:

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Text from "../../data/textFakeData";
import { Box, Container } from "@mui/material";
import '../assets/typo.css'
import LinearProgress from '@mui/material/LinearProgress';
import Timer from "../Timer";



export default function Main(props) {
   const [text, setText] = useState("");
   const [input, setInput] = useState("");
   const [lastLetter, setLastLetter] = useState("");
   const [words, setWords] = useState([]);
   const [wpm, setWpm] = useState(0);
   const [completed, setCompleted] = useState([]);
   const [isFinished, setIsFinished] = useState(false);
   const [startTime, setStartTime] = useState();
   const [started, setStarted] = useState(false);
   const [countDown, setCountDown] = useState(60);
   const [rootCount, setRootCount] = useState(countDown);
   const [countDownStatus, setCountDownStatus] = useState(false);
   const ref = useRef(null);

   //timer


   //set text
   useEffect(() => {
       setText(Text);
       setWords(Text.split(" "));
       setCompleted([]);
       setIsFinished(false);
       setWords([]);
       setText("");
       setInput("");
       setLastLetter("");
       setWpm(0);
       setRootCount(countDown);

   }, [])


   const calculateWpm = () => {

   }
   const handleStartGame = () => {
       setCompleted([]);
       setText(Text);
       //divided the paragraph into words array
       setWords(Text.split(" "));
       setStarted(true);
       setIsFinished(false);
       setStartTime(Date.now());
       setWpm(0);
   }
   const handleChange = (e) => {
       const input = e.target.value;
       const lastInput = input[input.length - 1];
       const current = words[0];
       console.log("input", input);
       console.log("lastInput", lastInput);
       console.log("current", current);
       //validate input with the paragraph
       if (lastInput === " ") {
           //check if it matches to current word
           if (input.trim() === current) {
               //remove word from the words array
               //clear the input;
               const newWords = [...words.slice(1)];
               console.log("newWords", newWords);
               //add current word to completed
               const newCompleted = [...completed, current];
               console.log("newCompleted", newCompleted);

               //setter
               setWords(newWords);
               setCompleted(newCompleted);
               setInput("");
               setIsFinished(newWords.length === 0);
               if (isFinished) {
                   setStarted(false);
               }
           }
       } else {
           setInput(input);
           setLastLetter(lastInput);
       }
       calculateWpm();


   }
   useEffect(() => {
       if (started) {
           countDown > 0 && setTimeout(() => setCountDown(countDown - 1), 1000);
           console.log("--");
       }
       countDown === 0 && setIsFinished(true);

   }, [countDown, started]);

   //render phase

   if (started && !isFinished) {
       return (
           <>
               <Box
                   sx={{
                       border: 1,
                       width: 1000,
                       padding: "2rem",
                       textAlign: "center",
                       display: "inline-block",
                       margin: "2rem auto",
                       fontWeight: "600"
                   }}
               >
                   <div>
                       <Timer value={countDown} />
                   </div>
                   <div>
                       <>WPM</>
                   </div>
                   <div>
                       <LinearProgress variant="determinate" value={100 / text.split(" ").length * completed.length} />
                   </div>
                   {/* This is for paragraph */}
                   <div style={
                       {
                           "display": "relative",
                           "left":0,
                           "top": 0
                       }
                   }>
                       <div className="typingField" id="text-container" onClick={() => { ref.current.focus() }}>
                           <p>
                               {
                                   text.split(" ").map((word, wordIndex) => {
                                       let highlight = false;
                                       let currentWord = false;

                                       //if word is completed ==> turn to green
                                       if (completed.length > wordIndex) {
                                           highlight = true;
                                       }
                                       if (completed.length === wordIndex) {
                                           currentWord = true;
                                       }
                                       return (
                                           <span key={wordIndex} className={`${highlight && "green"} ${currentWord && "underline"} word`}>
                                               {word.split("").map((letter, letterIndex) => {
                                                   //check if current word is type correctly
                                                   const isCurrentWord = wordIndex === completed.length;
                                                   const isIncorrectType = letter !== input[letterIndex];
                                                   const isHighlighted = letterIndex < input.length;
                                                   return (
                                                       <span className={`${isCurrentWord && isHighlighted
                                                           ? isIncorrectType
                                                               ? "red"
                                                               : "green"
                                                           : ""
                                                           }`} key={letterIndex}>
                                                           {letter}
                                                       </span>
                                                   )
                                               })}
                                           </span>
                                       )
                                   })}
                           </p>
                           <input type="text" ref={ref} onChange={handleChange} value={input} autoFocus={true} autoComplete={false} />
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </Box >
           </>
       )
   }
   if (started && isFinished) {
       return (
           <Box
               sx={{
                   border: 1,
                   width: 500,
                   padding: "2rem",
                   textAlign: "center",
                   display: "inline-block",
                   margin: "2rem auto"
               }}
           >
               <h2>
                   Your WPM is <strong>{wpm}</strong>
               </h2>
               <button className="start-btn" onClick={() => { setStarted(false); setCompleted(false); setCountDown(rootCount) }}>
                   Play again
               </button>
           </Box>
       )
   }
   else {
       return (
           <Box
               sx={{
                   border: 1,
                   width: 500,
                   padding: "2rem",
                   textAlign: "center",
                   display: "inline-block",
                   margin: "2rem auto"
               }}
           >
               <h2>Welcome to the Typing game</h2>
               <p>
                   <strong>Rules:</strong> <br />
                   Type in the input field the highlighted word. <br />
                   The correct words will turn <span className="green">green</span>.
                   <br />
                   Incorrect letters will turn <span className="red">red</span>.
                   <br />
                   <br />
                   Have fun!
               </p>
               <button className="start-btn" onClick={handleStartGame}>
                   Start game
               </button>
           </Box>
       );
   }
}
```

please give me some advice to solve this problem. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `react-scroll-bottom` library for scrolling to the bottom as soon as the new line is added. Link for the package [react-scroll-to-bottom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll-to-bottom)

Answer (score 0):

**Automatic Scroll to the target div in Reactjs**

First create two ref in your component for it to refer to the bottom div that we will create to target the scroll and second to refer to the parent of this div, also create a state to calculate the parent div's length. You can also you a scroll state as well, to trigger the state at specific condition (optional).

```
 const bottomRef = useRef<HTMLElement>(null);
 const parentRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
 const [height, setHeight] = useState<number>();
 const [scroll, setScroll] = useState<boolean>(false); //optional
```

Add parent ref to the parent div.

```
<div  ref={parentRef}>
```

Then just above your input div or below the div that you want to be at the bottom, add a span that we will use, to know the targeted bottom area to scroll to such as:

```
<span ref={bottomRef} />
```

Now we need a useEffect that will run on every render to calculate the height of our parent span/div in order to work without any delay/lag.

```
useEffect(() => setHeight(divRef.current?.clientHeight!));
```

After that we will create a function that will scroll to the bottom (targeted div).

```
const scrollToBottom = () => {
  bottomRef.current.scrollIntoView(true);
 };
```

Now we need to call this function when our required state(s) are changed.

```
useEffect(() => {
   scrollToBottom();
  }, [scroll, height]);
```